# How to Remove outer element in xml using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting below xml, i want to remove outer root element in jquery. Can anyone please help on us.

`<root ABC="YYYYY">
  <Row trancid="1" trancname="XXXXXXXX" selected="0" row_dst="0" /> 
  </root>`

Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the html of root element to use content without parent root node:

```
var str = '<root ABC="YYYYY"><Row trancid="1" trancname="XXXXXXXX" selected="0" row_dst="0" /></root>';
str = $(str).html()
```

Comment: @sreehari:works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/7spf7dhu/.
 can you reproduce problem in fiddle?

Comment: I verified it, it is working in fidler, but when i copy the same code to my page it is returning empty.

Comment: jQuery version using here is 1.6.2

Comment: Share the link of page

Comment: This is intranet site :(

Comment: @sreehari: Arghhh. try top repliacate problem in fiddle